# Need help understand and INSERT/UPDATE procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, plsql

I have an INSERT/UPDATE Procedure that will only seem to update when I change the existing "name".

I added a code field to the java, and want to update the code to the existing table without having to modify the "name" because it already exists.  If I modify the "name" then the "code" will get updated to that row in the table.

Can someone help me understand whats going or what I need to modify?

thanks

```
PROCEDURE update_things
  (things IN OUT things_bean, user_id IN NUMBER)
IS
  t_things   things_bean;
BEGIN
  -- If there is already an id set ... this is an update
  IF things.ID <> 0
  THEN
     SELECT things_bean (ID, NAME, code, work, foo)
       INTO t_things
       FROM things
      WHERE things.ID = ID;


     IF NOT things.equals (t_things)
     THEN

        things.foo:= t_things.foo;

        things.foo.modified_date := SYSDATE;
        things.foo.modified_by := user_id;

        UPDATE things
           SET NAME = things.NAME,
                              code = things.code,
               foo= things.foo
         WHERE ID = things.ID;
 END IF;                                                                                           


END update_things;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks to me like you should check this call:

```
things.equals(t_things)
```

to make sure your code value is part of the equality check.

Comment: You're right my friend...I had to add the check to the type body...we do things real weird here...thanks